# Issue with font rendering in browser

Tags: css, text, text-rendering, html-rendering

Result sample:
[font rendering issue sample](http://cdn.rawgit.com/strashylin/HTML_REPO/master/fl_issue.jpg)

As you can see two letters "f" and "l" are bold in every browsers and my styles.css doesn't have any rules for it. I'm not sure, but think that is due a problem with font's rendering ("HelveticaNeueW01-45Ligh, Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif").

I tried to use "text-rendering: optimizeLegibility" property, but it doesn't seem to help.

```
<p style="text-rendering: optimizelegibility;">Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the&nbsp;blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language&nbsp;ocean. A small river named Duden ﬂows. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of&nbsp;the Semantics.</p>
```

and Styles:

```
element {
    text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
}
body.home .entry-content p {
    margin: 20px 0px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeueW01-45Ligh",Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 1.9em;
}
body.home .entry-content p {
    margin: 20px 0px;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeueW01-45Ligh",Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 1.9em;
}
body.page-template-default .entry-content p {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.entry-content p {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    line-height: 1.7;
}
.entry-content p {
    margin: 0px 0px 15px;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    line-height: 1.7;
}
p {
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
body, button, input, select, textarea {
    color: #404040;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeueW01-55Roma",Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

What can I do to improve how this font is being rendered?

Comment: Probably a messed up ligature.

Comment: Which font of these is used?

Comment: Thank you  @BoltClock, sounds like same as my issue. Now I need realize how to fix it.

Comment: @Oriol, It uses "HelveticaNeueW01-45Ligh"

Comment: It might not be the solution you want to hear, but the easiest fix would probably be to just try using a different, similar font

Answer (score 0):

### text-redering / ligatures

You've mentioned already that you've tried the following css attribute.

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```

There may be a few more things for you to consider, from Article ["Make Your Web Pages More Legible With Ligatures"](http://demosthenes.info/blog/547/Make-Your-Web-Pages-More-Legible-With-CSS3-Ligatures-and-Kerning-Pairs):

*"To turn on standard ligatures, use:"*

```
     p { font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures; }
```

*"To gain support in all browsers, while using text-rendering: optimizeLegibility as a fallback":*

```
p {
    /* optional: for older browsers */
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; 

     /* for iOS and Safari 6 */
    -webkit-font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures;

    /* for up-to-date browsers, including IE10 and Opera 21 */ 
    font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures; 
}
```

Recommended article:

- [Css-Tricks: text-rendering](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-rendering/)

---

### font-smoothing

Another way to improve font appearance:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; // chrome - safari
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; // mozilla
```

Two recommended articles:

- [Font smoothing explained](http://szafranek.net/works/articles/font-smoothing-explained/)
- [Font Smoothing in Webkit and Firefox](http://davidwalsh.name/font-smoothing)